# Is addToBackStack adding current or new fragment to back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm quite confused about usage of adding fragment manager's addToBackStack function. When we replace fragments, is addToBackStack(...) adding current fragment to backstack, or the one that will be replaced?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addToBackStack` is used to put the current fragment into the stack, before going to the next fragment

[As documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))

> Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the
>   transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse
>   its operation when later popped off the stack.

Meaning:

if you are currently one fragment `A` and move to fragment `B`.

Fragment `A` is now in the back stack.

When you press back while on fragment `B` you will go back to fragment `A`